# XHR from another domain to a https server

Tags: heroku, xmlhttprequest, ionic-framework

I have a server on heroku, using https certificate.  Now I am trying to build an IOS/Android app using Ionic framework and make connection to that heroku server.

The error when I do it is
"ERR CONNECTION REFUSED" when I am trying to do https://example.com/auth

And when I change it to http instead, the error is
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/auth. The request was redirected to 'https://www.example.com/auth', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Not familiar with `Ionic`, but did you specify a port anywhere in your App? You may also need to request permission to use the internet connection. Did you try testing against a third party API that you know works?

Comment: since cordova 5.0.0, cordova-plugin-whitelist is mandatory to perform XHR queries to other domain. add it and configure it. shall be ok to https

Comment: I run a node/express server on heroku and use it with my ionic app. I had to have the cordova-plugin-whitelist and you also have to enable CORS on your server.